# How GRE score affect your acceptance rate

Tags: graduate-admissions

Suppose you are very bad at undergraduate but did well on your GRE test. How would that affect you application?

Comment: Acceptance rate for what?

Comment: Grad school. not necessarily Phd, could be Masters. Also could be in other countries.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little, but don't count on it putting you over the line. Admissions isn't a numbers game at most institutions. Lots of bits of evidence suggest that you will, or won't, be a good candidate and a success in the program. You need to build a complete picture that has enough good points to outweigh any bad ones.

If you were a bad undergraduate that is a problem that you need to overcome, or at least explain. What were you bad at? Good? How does math fit in here, assuming that is your field? What else have you done? Do you have any research experience? What are your goals and do you have a plan to achieve them.

All of these things can matter, but a good GRE is positive, at least. What else have you got?

Comment: Research experience, extra curriculum activities involving learning teaching. Have being a grader for two classes, substituted TA for his tutorial... Cooked for a organization for homeless people, participated to conferences. Participated to competitions. But took 8 years to finish undergrad. GPA is so so

Comment: Good. Focus on the positive. Build a positive picture.